# Compare two excel files in python

Tags: python, excel, file-comparison

```py
import xlrd
wb_1 = xlrd.open_workbook('Book1.xls', on_demand=True)
ws_1 = wb_1.sheet_by_name('Sheet3')
wb_2 = xlrd.open_workbook('Book2.xls', on_demand=True)
ws_2 = wb_2.sheet_by_name('Sheet3')
for i in range(ws_1.ncols):
    col_value1 = ws_1.cell_value(0, i)
    for cell in range(ws_1.nrows):
        cell_value1 = ws_1.cell(cell, i)
        for j in range(ws_2.ncols):
            col_value2 = ws_2.cell_value(0, i)       
            for cell in range(ws_2.nrows):
                cell_value2 = ws_2.cell(cell, i)
                if cell_value2 == cell_value1:
                    print('same')
```

Im trying to compare two excel worksheets, Im not sure whether im going in a right way.
How to find the changed values

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code for extracting row and columns differences.

```
import xlrd
wb_1 = xlrd.open_workbook('Book1.xlsx', on_demand=True)
ws_1 = wb_1.sheet_by_name('Sheet3')

rw,cl,rw2,cl2=[[] for i in range(4)]

for i in range(0,ws_1.ncols):
    col_value1 = ws_1.cell(0, i).value
    cl.append(col_value1)
    for cell in range(0,ws_1.nrows):
        row_value1 = ws_1.cell(cell, i).value
        rw.append(row_value1)

wb_2 = xlrd.open_workbook('Book2.xlsx', on_demand=True)
ws_2 = wb_2.sheet_by_name('Sheet3')        

for i in range(0,ws_2.ncols):
    col_value2 = ws_2.cell(0, i).value
    cl2.append(col_value2)
    for cell in range(0,ws_2.nrows):
        row_value2 = ws_2.cell(cell, i).value
        rw2.append(row_value2)

for i in range(len(cl)):
    for j in range(len(cl2)):
        if cl[i]!=cl2[j]:
            print("column difference",i,j)

for i in range(len(rw)):
    for j in range(len(rw2)):
        if rw[i]!=rw2[j]:
            print("row difference",i,j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert Excel into CSV file, it will seperate your values with commas. Library is called CSV
Just "import csv"
Then open file using "with", get rows with column names and you will get list or dictionary ( depends on approach )
You'll have to just compare list indexes and that's the easiest way.

Read article:
https://realpython.com/python-csv/